# Finding Duplicate Orders (by time proximity)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of orders that I know have duplicates

```
    customer   order_number   order_date
   ----------  ------------   -------------------
          1             1     2012-03-01 01:58:00
          1             2     2012-03-01 02:01:00
          1             3     2012-03-01 02:03:00
          2             4     2012-03-01 02:15:00
          3             5     2012-03-01 02:18:00
          3             6     2012-03-01 04:30:00
          4             7     2012-03-01 04:35:00
          5             8     2012-03-01 04:38:00
          6             9     2012-03-01 04:58:00
          6            10     2012-03-01 04:59:00
```

I want to find all duplicates (order by same customer within 60 minutes of eachother). Either a resultset consisting of the 'duplicate' rows or a set of all customers with a count of how many duplicates.

Here is what I have tried

```
SELECT
   customer,
   count(*)
FROM
   orders
GROUP BY
   customer,
   DATEPART(HOUR, order_date)
HAVING (count(*) > 1)
```

This doesn't work when duplicates are within 60 minutes of each other but are in different hours i.e 1:58 and 2:02

I've also tried this

```
SELECT
  o1.customer,
  o1.order_number,
  o2.order_number,
  DATEDIFF(MINUTE,o1.order_date, o2.order_date) AS [diff]
FROM
  orders o1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
  orders o2 ON o1.customer = o2.customer AND o1.order_number <> o2.order_number
WHERE
  ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,o1.order_date, o2.order_date)) < 60
```

Now this gives me all of the duplicates but it also gives me multiple rows per duplicate order. i.e (o1, o2) and (o2, o1) which wouldn't be so bad if there were'nt some orders with multiple duplicates. In those cases I get (o1, o2), (o1,o3), (o2, o1), (o2, o3), (o3, o1), (o3, o2) etc. I get all of the permutations.

Anyone have some insight? I'm not necessarily looking for the best performing answer here, just one that works.

Comment: You have a cascade dependancy.  If you have orders that happen at `(0, 59, 118, 177, 236, etc) *[all 59 minutes appart]*, what do you want the result of your search to be?

Comment: @Dems interesting. I would consider all of those duplicates. However I'd be happy with a result in either case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM orders AS lookup
                     WHERE customer    = orders.customer
                       AND order_date <  orders.order_date
                       AND order_date >= DATEADD(hour, -1, order_date)
                   )
       THEN 'Principle Order'
       ELSE 'Duplicate Order'
  END as Order_Status
FROM
  orders
```

Using `EXISTS` and a correlated sub-query you can check if there were any preceding orders in the last hour.

Comment: Assumes no two orders happen at the exact same time.  Can be changed to `<= AND >` instead of `< AND >=` and then add `id < orders.id`.

Comment: Thanks. I had to tweak a couple of minor things but conceptually this works for me. This is kind of what I was thinking about as a solution but after staring at it for so long I gave up. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

**Test data:**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(customer INT,order_number INT,order_date DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
    (1,1,'2012-03-01 01:58:00'),
    (1,2,'2012-03-01 02:01:00'),
    (1,3,'2012-03-01 02:03:00'),
    (2,4,'2012-03-01 02:15:00'),
    (3,5,'2012-03-01 02:18:00'),
    (3,6,'2012-03-01 04:30:00'),
    (4,7,'2012-03-01 04:35:00'),
    (5,8,'2012-03-01 04:38:00'),
    (6,9,'2012-03-01 04:58:00'),
    (6,10,'2012-03-01 04:59:00')
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        MIN(datediff(minute,'1990-1-1',order_date)) OVER(PARTITION BY customer) AS minDate,
        datediff(minute,'1990-1-1',order_date) AS DateTicks,
        tbl.customer
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT
    CTE.customer,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (CTE.DateTicks-CTE.minDate)<60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
    CTE
GROUP BY
    CTE.customer
```

Comment: This only compares to the first order though?  What about orders that happen at minutes `(0,1,2,65,66,67)`?  Orders at `(1,2,66,67)` are duplicates, but won't this only find `(1,2)`?

Comment: +1 I'm giving this a shot against my real data, thanks for the response.

Comment: @Dems: I don't follow you. This will take the min of the customer group and then subtract the current datetime. This will also take the full datetime in minutes (ticks).

Comment: @Arion - If there are three orders close together, 2 are duplicates.  If there is a fourth order more than an hour later, it's not a duplicate.  If there is then a fifth order 5 minutes after the fourth order, that is a duplicate.  Your code only compares the fifth order to the first order though.  This means that it is not shown as a duplicate.  How would you plan to see that the fifth is a duplicate of the fourth order?

Comment: @Dems- Right. That I have not taken in consideration. You are correct. It will only take the first in the customer "group".

Answer (score 1):

The following query identifies all possible permutations of orders within the proximity of 60 minutes of one another:

```
DECLARE @orders TABLE (CustomerId INT, OrderId INT, OrderDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @orders
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2012-03-01 01:58:00'),
    (1, 2, '2012-03-01 02:01:00'),
    (1, 3, '2012-03-01 02:03:00'),
    (2, 4, '2012-03-01 02:15:00'),
    (3, 5, '2012-03-01 02:18:00'),
    (3, 6, '2012-03-01 04:30:00'),
    (4, 7, '2012-03-01 04:35:00'),
    (5, 8, '2012-03-01 04:38:00'),
    (6, 9, '2012-03-01 04:58:00'),
    (6, 10, '2012-03-01 04:59:00');

with ProximityOrderCascade(CustomerId, OrderId, ProximateOrderId, MinutesDifference, OrderDate, ProximateOrderDate)
as 
(
    select o.customerid, o.orderid, null, null, o.orderdate, o.orderdate
    from @orders o
    union all   
    select o.customerid, o.orderid, p.orderid, datediff(minute, p.OrderDate, o.OrderDate), o.OrderDate, p.OrderDate
    from ProximityOrderCascade p
    inner join @orders o 
        on p.customerid = o.customerid 
        and abs(datediff(minute, p.OrderDate, o.OrderDate)) between 0 and 60 
        and o.orderid <> p.orderid
    where proximateorderid is null
)
select * from ProximityOrderCascade
where 
    not ProximateOrderId is null
```

From there, you can transform the results into a query of your choice. The results of this function identify only customers 1 and 6 as having 'duplicate' orders.

```
CustomerId  OrderId     ProximateOrderId MinutesDifference OrderDate               ProximateOrderDate
----------- ----------- ---------------- ----------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
6           9           10               -1                2012-03-01 04:58:00.000 2012-03-01 04:59:00.000
6           10          9                1                 2012-03-01 04:59:00.000 2012-03-01 04:58:00.000
1           1           3                -5                2012-03-01 01:58:00.000 2012-03-01 02:03:00.000
1           2           3                -2                2012-03-01 02:01:00.000 2012-03-01 02:03:00.000
1           1           2                -3                2012-03-01 01:58:00.000 2012-03-01 02:01:00.000
1           3           2                2                 2012-03-01 02:03:00.000 2012-03-01 02:01:00.000
1           2           1                3                 2012-03-01 02:01:00.000 2012-03-01 01:58:00.000
1           3           1                5                 2012-03-01 02:03:00.000 2012-03-01 01:58:00.000

(8 row(s) affected)
```